# Описание телефона клиента в CommerceML

Tags: 1с, xml

Пишу генератор CommerceML для выгрузки с сайта в 1С. Столкнулся с невозможностью указать телефон для контрагента при выгрузке информации о заказах.

Судя по спецификации CommerceML 2, должно быть так:

```
<Документ>
...
<Контрагенты>
...
<Контрагент>
...
<Контакты>
...
<Контакт>
    <Тип>Телефон мобильный</Тип>
    <Значение>123456</Значение>
</Контакт>
<Контакт>
    <Тип>Почта</Тип>
    <Значение>customer@mail.ru</Значение>
</Контакт>
...
```

Поле почта экспортируется отлично, но телефон не подгружается. Собственно, если у кого есть рабочие файлы выгрузки документов, то секция контакт была бы очень кстати.

Comment: Вот [xsd](http://v8.1c.ru/edi/edi_stnd/90/CML205.XSD) есть. Возможные значения: ТелефонВнутренний, ТелефонРабочий, ТелефонМобильный, ТелефонДомашний, Пейджер, Факс, Почта, ICQ, ВебСайт

Comment: Пробовал:

  <Контакт>
    <Тип>Телефон</Тип>
    <Значение>89251233232</Значение>
  </Контакт>

Тоже самое. И даже <Тип>ТелефонМобильный</Тип> пробовал - тоже 0 реакции =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кстати в описании они наврали. Правильно действительно как у вас: "Телефон мобильный", в xsd описании типа КонтактТип значения с пробелом.

Посмотрел загрузку в 1С (УТ 11.0.9.12) загружаются только "Почта" и "ТелефонРабочий". В общем либо пользоваться только этими значениями, либо конфигурацию менять...

Подозреваю, что функционал на 100% не используется по причине редкого использования. Поди битрикс только эти два типа и умеет грузить...

Comment: В принципе, телефон всё-равно какой использовать, главное, чтобы он отображался. Попробую ТелефонРабочий, может быть получится.

Comment: Работает! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

**Yura Ivanov** дал правильный ответ - использовать "ТелефонРабочий" вместо "Телефон мобильный".

PS. Если модераторы выделят комментарий в отдельный ответ и сделают его верным - будет здорово :)